# rake aborted! SystemStackError: stack level too deep

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, cloud9

**SystemStackError: stack level too deep**
I'm having trouble while deploying to heroku.

I searched before posting here and followed some tips.

Added precompile config in config/application.rb

```
class Application < Rails::Application
    config.i18n.default_locale = [ :en ]
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'
  config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
  end
end
```

And then,

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile

$ git add -A
$ git commit -m .
$ git push heroku master
```

This is full trace for heroku push.

```
Bundle completed (17.33s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.2). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       The latest bundler is 1.16.2, but you are currently running 1.15.2.
       To update, run `gem install bundler`
-----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       ** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
       ** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
       ** Execute assets:environment
       ** Invoke environment (first_time)
       ** Execute environment
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated
       rake aborted!
       SystemStackError: stack level too deep
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
in <class:Numeric>'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:137:in `local_cache_key'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:74:in `middleware'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application/bootstrap.rb:65:in `block in <module:Bootstrap>'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:389:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.3/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_dc2cd42e7f5a928ff12204be7d379467/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

I found something and think this problem is like a method call duplicate.

But, I couldn't figure it out what file I need to fix.

Please give me some tips.

Thank you, have a good day !.

Oh, I'm using cloud9, Rails-4.1.8, and Ruby 2.4.0 if this is helpful.

Comment: You need to post more code I think. I do see an extra `end` in your `application.rb` file, is that intended ?, was that a typo while you posted the code on stack overflow, or is it also a typo in your app?

Comment: This error is mostly occurs when there are infinite loops inside each other that the stack overflows! Check out your code again for endless loops.

Comment: You upgrade ruby or rails? From ruby 2.4 fixnum and bignum are same thing as integer, that's the problem, you need to make changes according to that

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem.